# What does 'one' in this sentence refer to?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, pronouns

> The past decade has seen a growing public fascination with the complex
>   “connectedness” of modern society. At the heart of this fascination is
>   the idea of a network – a pattern of interconnections among a set of
>   things – and **one** finds networks appearing in discussion and
>   commentary on an enormous range of topics.

What does **one** mean here?

[[Source: Networks, Crowds, and Markets]](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521195331&ss=exc)

Comment: *one* refers to a generic person it could mean you or I

Comment: What does your research on the pronoun *one* show? Why do you think "one" should refer to anything in the sentence? Can you tell us why?

Comment: It's merely part of a device to avoid the outlandish passive variant 'and networks are found to be appearing in discussion and commentary on an enormous range of topics.'

Comment: Include in your question the research you’ve done. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example sentence, "one" is not a determiner but a pronoun. It refers to "any indefinite person" (Collins dictionary). It is possible that the authors chose a sentence construction with "one" in order to avoid a passive construction ("and networks can be found appearing ...").

In less formal English, "one" can often be replaced with "you" ("and you can find networks appearing ...").